# Диск с поврежденными секторами

Tags: hdd

У меня есть ssd, на котором стоит ОС и многие программы. Есть винчестер на 1 тб, но у него какие-то секторы повреждены, что-то грузится на него, что-то нет. Как-то раз я его отформатировал и забил примерно на 400гб и все работало норм, но потом что-то загрузил и все полетело. Щас хочу повторить магию, есть какие-то рекомендации как лучше использовать диск, чтобы еще поработал? Может указать какой-то определенный размер кластера, файловая система ntfs. Я пытался через акроник восстановить поврежденные сектора, 3 дня стоял что-то делал в итоге никакого эффекта..

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: 1) Выполните переназначение повреждённых секторов (MHDD, Victoria - операция Remap). 2) Форматируйте. 3) Запишите состояние SMART (особенно кол-во переназначенных и помеченных к переназначению секторов). 4) Погоняйте недельку. 5) Ежедневно сравнивайте СМАРТ с записанным - если количество хреновых секторов растёт, винт в помойку. Иначе - можно использовать, но без доверия.

Comment: Спасибо, попробую

Comment: Если диск начал аппаратно сыпаться, то вряд-ли какие-то программные средства смогут его оживить.

Comment: @pepsicoca1, мне главное, чтобы из одного тб можно было использовать хотя бы гигов 300

Comment: @Akina, у меня за час выполнился 1%, если все будет продолжаться в таком духе, то на это все уйдет, примерно, 4 дня. И за этот один процент такая картина(добавил скрин в вопрос). Есть смысл продолжать?

Comment: Диск-то старый? Куплен был новым? MTBF на диски сейчас примерно 10 лет. Если диску 5 лет, то вполне может начать сыпаться, особенно если был сильно нагружен. Иногда умельцы продают б/у диски из датацентров, которые работали в режиме 24/7. Совет: выкиньте и не мучайтесь. Новый диск сейчас стоит 100 долларов. Еще попробуйте подключить диск к другой машине. Может это не диск посыпался, а контроллер диска у Вас барахлит. Или 12 вольт просело в системе, шпиндель не набирает обороты и диск сходит с ума.

Comment: подключал к другому пк, та же фигня. Ему 4 года, плюс минус пару месяцев. Возможно, я не обращался с ним достаточно аккуратно.

Comment: *Есть смысл продолжать?* Пока криминала явного не видать, ошибок не зарегистрировано. Лог предупреждений о времени доступа 200-600 отключите, незачем